# Sampling order of rejection sampling

Tags: sampling, accept-reject

Consider a target density $f(y) \leq C \, g(y)$, where it is easy to make samples from density $g$. We can draw samples from $f$ by repeating the following routine:

1. Draw $Y \sim g$
2. Draw $U \sim \mathrm{unif}[0, 1]$
3. If $U \leq f(Y) \,/ \,(C \, g(Y))$ then accept, otherwise reject.

My question is about a claim from a paper **Beskos, A. Exact simulation of diffusions. The Annals of Applied Probability, 2005. Page 2423**:

> This traditional rejection sampling algorithm seems to imply a fixed
> order in the acquisition of the required random elements:
> specifically, the proposed variate Y precedes the decision variate U.

I cannot understand this claim. Although the authors later proved that the order does not matter, I could not follow how it is natural to think that the order matters. Do we really need to prove that the order does not matter, since $Y$ and $U$ are independently drawn?

Comment: This may be a minor remark. Unless the authors propose an alternative where only accepted $Y$'s are simulated.

Comment: In addition, if one envisions the simulation of $(Y,U)$ as a point over the subgraph of g, this is one single simulation, rather than a succession. The only case when $U$ would not be simulated is when $f(Y)=0$.

Comment: @mdzz it seems a rather strange thing to even bother asserting; I'd imagine it's obvious to even pretty naive readers that it makes no difference whether U is generated before the proposal for Y or after it.

Comment: @Glen_b I agree with you. But from the context I feel that the authors may have a good reason to assert it. Hopefully someone from the field could answer.